# Traducción para "burgers with all the trimmings"

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, comida, español-neutral

Tengo en la cocina de casa un pequeño póster al estilo de los Estados Unidos de los años 50, con una imagen de una hamburguesa que cuesta 50 céntimos y el texto siguiente:

> Burgers with all the trimmings

[image: Burgers with all the trimmings]

En este caso *trimmings* se refiere a "cualquier condimento o elemento adicional que se añade a la hamburguesa". Yo automáticamente traduzco esa expresión al español así:

> Hamburguesas con todos sus avíos

Aquí en Andalucía (España) usamos la palabra *[avíos](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4a5NnJb)* con un poco de libertad. Según el diccionario, la acepción más cercana es la siguiente:

> 5. m. pl. Utensilios necesarios para algo. *Avíos de escribir, de coser, de afeitar.*

Si sustituís la palabra *utensilios* por *ingredientes* tenéis la definición exacta que usamos aquí. Por ejemplo, solemos hablar mucho de "los avíos del puchero" para referirnos a todo lo que hace falta para prepararlo: las verduras, los garbanzos, los huesos de jamón, etc. Y en el caso de la hamburguesa, los *avíos* son simplemente lo que hace falta para hacer una buena hamburguesa (además de la propia hamburguesa, claro): queso, beicon, lechuga, tomate, ketchup, mostaza...

Sin embargo, se me hace que esta palabra pueda sonar demasiado andaluza, no sé si se usa en el resto del mundo hispanohablante (incluyendo el resto de España). Así pues, pregunta: ¿se usa *avíos* de esta forma en el resto del mundo (o, al menos, se entendería)? ¿Cuál sería una forma más adecuada de expresar esta idea de modo que se entienda mejor para todos los hispanohablantes?

Comment: pues si trim es corte, trimmer es recortadora, pues trimming serian los recortes? hablando de todas esas cosas que se cortan o pican para poder dentro de la hamburguesa

Comment: Dunno. I always say, “drag it through the garden”

Answer (score 5):

[WordReference lo traduce](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=trimmings) como:

- guarniciones
- adornos (figurado)

Efectivamente, [*guarnición*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JklZZCp) lo define el DLE como:

> 2. f. Complemento, generalmente de hortalizas, legumbres, etc., que se sirve con la carne o el pescado.

El uso de *guarniciones*, por contra, sí me encaja bastante, por lo que la frase 'Burgers with all the trimmings' creo que tendría una buena candidato de traducción en:

**Hamburgueras con su guarnición**

En cuanto al uso de *avíos*, yo nunca lo había oído y, por tanto, en mi zona nordeste de España no es nada común.

Comment: El cuerpo de la pregunta se va deslizando hacia el uso de _avíos_, por lo que respondí a ambas cosas.

Comment: Sí, la verdad es que media pregunta se centra en la palabra _avíos_ y al final me he dado cuenta de que en realidad estoy haciendo dos preguntas en una (aunque la de _avíos_ se responde rápido por lo que veo). Por cierto, ¿no sería mejor decir "hamburguesas con su guarnición"? No sé, pero me suena mejor en singular en este caso, ya que "guarnición" se refiere (incluso usada en singular) a todo lo que acompaña.

Comment: no considero guarnición la palabra correcta, por lo común la guarnición acompaña al platillo,mientras que los trimmings y toppings van arriba o dentro de esta haciéndola parte del platillo mismo, por eso me parece que complemento es la opción mas adecuada.

Answer (score 4):

Creo que en España, fuera de Andalucía, no se entendería ese uso de **avíos**. Propongo varías alternativas:

[**Añadido**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=30jXGNR)

> 2. m. Añadidura, adición.

[**Complemento**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=A1KrS6q)

> 1. m. Cosa, cualidad o circunstancia que se añade a otra para hacerla íntegra o perfecta.

[**Arreos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3jLocDD):

> 3. m. pl. Adherentes o cosas menudas que pertenecen a otra principal o se usan con ella.

(aunque no creo que sea ampliamente entendida)

Comment: No, "arreo" no creo que se use apenas, pero me mola la palabra. :-)

Comment: los arreos son accessorios físicos y de decoración, como escuadras, mandiles, martillos, etc... creo que complemento es la mejor opcion

Answer (score 2):

En varios países latinoamericanos (concretamente, sé de Colombia y México) y de manera informal, se diría simplemente "un ____ **con todo**" o "una ____ **con todo**". Como ejemplos: en México se habla de "tacos con todo", y en Colombia se usa "hamburguesa con todo".